# facebook page: where are our apps listed

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have created an facebbok app for a client. The app works fine.

But the app is not listed on the client's facebook page. The client wants it to be listed.

Is it possible to list a fb page's registered apps on the fb page?

(see screenshot of their page and app [here](http://www.keleia.com/dev/screenshot_fb_page__app_not_listed.jpg))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by list, but I'm assuming you mean you want to add the app to the page. You can add the app to the page using the FB JavaScript SDK and the following code:

```
var obj = {
    method: 'pagetab',
    redirect_uri: '[url_to_your_app]'
};
FB.ui(obj);
```

Comment: Nirah, could I request that you take a look at the screenshot that I provided in the original question. The screenshot shows: 1) the client's fb page, and 2) the client's fb app. From the screenshot I believe that you can see that their fb page does not have any indicators (such as a List of Apps or whatever) that they have apps/games to go play with.

Comment: I had a look at your screenshot - it still wasn't useful. You cannot have a 'list' of apps / games on the page. You either add the app to the page and have a nice photo of the app, or 'Like' the App / Game's fan page so it appears under the "Page's Favourites".

Comment: If you had an example screenshot of how you wanted it to look, that would have been better.

Comment: could I ask you to elaborate on this: __add the app to the page and have a nice photo of the app__, maybe as a new answer.

Also, is your first answer still a possible solution? I am currently looking through my html and I do not have the js api installed, but if somehow that can solve my problem (to __somehow__ showcase their app on their page) then I am willing to try that route.

Comment: When you add the app to the page, you will be able to customise the small image that appears next to Likes, Photos etc. Give it a try first at least - it's what you are after.

Comment: aha ... I think we are talking about 2 different things. I think what you are talking about is 'posting to wall' (such as when a fb user (or fb page admin.) posts to their wall, or likes something which then appears on their wall, or shares something which then appears on their wall) ... this functionality works fine: the client's app has a fb share button.

I have a different thing in mind however. I want a permanent link to the client's fb app/game listed on the client's fb page that their visitors can easily find and click (and goto and play).

thanks.